# How to position background dynamical based on resolution

Tags: css, svg, background, clip

struggling with issue how to set background image - static or SVG shape for top right corner in way it's pulled from outside of view area.

Imagine you have site with minimal width ~ 1000 px - image is clipped in top right corner partially. When width of page will grow to max width image will be unclipped / unmasked fully.

There is no scale in size of image. Just horizontal clipp / mask - attached screenshots might give such impression but it's just because of different scale while making print screen.

Image in top left stays all the time. Red rectangle represents page area.

Top right image is like

```
    <svg width="1868" height="899" viewBox="0 0 1868 899" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1044.32 -1144.66L1757.62 -735.936C1825.92 -696.799 1868 -624.454 1868 -546.161V271.161C1868 349.454 1825.92 421.799 1757.62 460.936L1044.32 869.66C976.052 908.78 891.948 908.78 823.677 869.66L110.379 460.936C42.0777 421.799 0 349.454 0 271.161L0 -546.161C0 -624.454 42.0777 -696.799 110.379 -735.936L823.677 -1144.66C891.948 -1183.78 976.052 -1183.78 1044.32 -1144.66Z" fill="#17212F"/>
</svg>
```

Any ideas?

Kind Regards,

Jan

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you want, What does the images represent ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Which image? Those two are taken from graphic design - the dark hexagon should be always clipped from top but should be somehow pulled from right if page is resized - wider.

Comment: So you want that shape to be like the first image at all time. Right?

Comment: @ZohirSalak No. I want to have the dark image being partially clipped for lower resolutions e.g. 1920 * 1080 px but if page is wide e.g. 3840 * 1080 px it should be like on the second image - fully shown.

Comment: This feels really messy, you can play along with viewport units, you'll have to care for the position as well as the size of the image, Also you might want to edit the svg to give it few space from the top so when it goes down it can look like the first image otherwise you'll quickly see the other half of the triangle.

Comment: you may try a combination of:`background-size` and 
`background-position`